# keras input not matching output confusion

Tags: keras, tf.keras

I am trying to implement a silly learn to rank example.  Essentially, I have 2 descriptions of a location, size and number of bathrooms.  I want to "combine" them to create a score.  Then I wish to compare the scores for the "best".  I will always be comparing 3 locations at a time.

The neuralnetwork I expect to do this:

```
# 3 locations with 2 descriptions. 
rinputs = Input(shape=(3, 2), name ='inputlayer')

# take my 3 expected inputs, split them
split = Lambda( lambda x: tf.split(x,num_or_size_splits=3,axis=1))(rinputs)
input_one_tensor = split[0]
input_two_tensor = split[1]
input_three_tensor = split[2]

# combine each set of location elements into 1 "score"
layer2 = Dense(1, name = 'Layer2', use_bias = True, activation = 'sigmoid')  # 60 was better than 100
layer2a = layer2(input_one_tensor)
layer2b = layer2(input_two_tensor)
layer2c = layer2(input_three_tensor)

concatLayer = Concatenate(name = 'ConcatLayer2')([layer2a,layer2b, layer2c])

# softmax my score to get "best selection"
softmaxLayer = Dense(3, activation='softmax', name = 'softmax', use_bias = False)
softmaxLayer = softmaxLayer(concatLayer)

model = Model(inputs=rinputs, outputs=softmaxLayer)

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I now create my test data:

```
loc1 = [1, 5]
loc2 = [4, 1]
loc3 = [6, 7]

# create two entries for my trial run
inputs = np.asarray([[loc1, loc2, loc3], [loc3,loc3,loc1]]).reshape(2,3,2)
ytrue = np.asarray([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]).reshape(2,3)

model.fit(inputs, ytrue,verbose=True,)
```

But then I get the following error about my outputs.  That I am not understanding.

```
File "/.virtualenvs/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1990, in categorical_crossentropy
    return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
File "/.virtualenvs/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5529, in categorical_crossentropy
    target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 1, 3) are incompatible
```

I'm not entirely understanding why the shapes don't match.  I expect my softmax layer to output 3 numbers that sum to 1 and can be compared to my ytrue.

any insights appreciated

Comment: Can you advise what a, b, and c are in `np.asarray([[a, b, c], [c,c,a]])`?

Comment: sorry will fix, but a=loc1, b=loc2, c=loc3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from the model architecture itself, it seems like you just need a two-dimensional data to be fed into Layer2:

[image]

**One may use a *Reshape/Flatten layer* to fix it.**

By reshaping the output of Lambda layer from `(None, 1, 2)` to `(None, 2)`, the final output's shape should become compatible too `(None, 3)`.

**Additional notes:**
As an example borrowed (with some modifications) from the [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split) website, let's assume we want to split an input tensor of the shape of `(3, 2)` into 3 smaller tensors along the axis=1:

```
x = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([3, 2], -1, 1))
s0, s1, s2 = tf.split(x, num_or_size_splits=3, axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Here are the smaller tensor splits:

[image]

Now, we can see the shape is `(1, 2)`, i.e. a 2D tensor consistent with the tensor it is derived from, and not a vector of the shape of `(2,)`. In the context of your problem, for a batch, that would be `(None, 1, 2)`.

Comment: thanks! i will try this.  How should i interpret the difference between (None,1,2) vs (None,2)?  This might be where my conceptual model is breaking down?

Comment: I added some notes to the answer to clarify. Please feel free to update me on how your model works...